# Soft Delete VS Hard Delete in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, soft-delete

What is the better way or best way to delete an `item` in Laravel? The `Soft Delete` or the `Hard Delete`? and why? I will implement it in my future projects.

Answer (score 3):

I think this very much depends on the nature of the `item`.

For example, when building data driven web apps where content can be created, updated and deleted by users, or I'm deleting critical data, I always use soft deletes.

Why? Because users have a tendency to accidentally delete data and it's much easier to restore soft deleted data, than to cherry pick and restore data from database backups.

If the data being deleted is non critical and will definitely never be needed again, then hard deletes will most likely be the better solution.

This is all of course only an opinion. Take it as you will. I would be interested to hear what others have to say on the topic.

Comment: Great explanation. I also want to hear other's answer :)